# Which ZK proving systems are statistically vs computationally zero knowledge?

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, quantum-cryptanalysis

I was curious which of Groth16, Halo2, Bulletproofs, etc have statistical vs computational zero knowledge guarantees. This would inform post-quantum zero knowledge as well, since I imagine that past statistical zero knowledge systems will not be de-anonymized, but past computational zk may. (Note that I am not concerned about soundness.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, all of the above, and essentially all ZK-SNARKs, have statistical zero-knowledge. More precisely, Groth16 can be instantiated in two modes, providing either statistical zero-knowledge or statistical soundness - ZK-SNARKs typically cannot provide statistical soundness, but statistical zero-knowledge is usually easy to achieve. Indeed, statistical zero-knowledge is in particular quantum-proof.